# Is mobile switch, mobile tools modules in drupal works in localhost?

Tags: drupal-7

I installed & configure mobile switch, mobile tool module and mobile theme in my drupal7 in my local machine. I see the site in android emulator. Its not changed to mobile theme. Please help me out guys